# UICollectionView with dynamic Cell Identifier

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I want UICollection view to have dynamic CellIdentifier
like follwoing.

```
    NSString *strIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cellIdentifier%d",indexPath.row];
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:strIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

How can I do this? If its possible Please Help!!!
Thanks

EDIT

I have registered all my identifiers with this code

```
    //CollectionView
    self.mpCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width,  frame.size.height) collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [self.mpCollectionView setDataSource:self];
    [self.mpCollectionView setDelegate:self];
    for(int i=0;i<arrayExplorerItems.count;i++)
    {
        NSString* strIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cellIdentifier%d",i];
        NSLog(@"registered Id:%@",strIdentifier);
        [self.mpCollectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:strIdentifier];
    }

 and my cellForItemAtIndeaxPath is 

    UICollectionViewCell *cell;
    NSString *strIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cellIdentifier%d",indexPath.row];
    cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:strIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

but giving me this error

could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier cellIdentifier0 - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: Where/When are you executing the register code loop?

Comment: Soon after allocation of collectionview

Comment: I'm are you getting NSLog for registered before cellForItem is called?

Comment: @rounak I am Not getting Log

Comment: Then your code isn't getting executed. There's a problem with your control flow/logic, not a problem with UICollectionView

Comment: yes might be , I am trying... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You need to register all cell identifiers first.

```
[collectionView registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:]
```

or

```
[collectionView registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:]
```

Then you can create and dequeue all prepared identifiers without trouble.

Comment: how do I register different Identifiers?